# advanced filtering in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have to create an application which shows some data in Recycler view and set up an advance filtring options.  The main options to search should be listed in the left hand side and if an item is being selected, set of options which is specifying the range with check boxes should be displayed accordingly. I cant set this view using layouts please help me to do this.     [image]

here is the output I expect 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBrdu.png)

please help me to do this thanks in advance

this is what i did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jijoabraham.informe.search"
android:background="#ffffff">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="#FF00BCD4"

    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#1d2643"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sales Report"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layright"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layleft"
    android:layout_above="@+id/laybottom"
    android:background="#ffffff"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layleft"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/laybottom"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dte_btn"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onSelect"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Branch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/branch_btn"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onSelect"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Reports"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/reports_btn"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onSelect"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/laybottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Apply Filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this type of layouts with the help of fragments easily. 
Create four different fragments:

- FilterMenuFragment for your left most screen.
- DateFilterFragment for your right side screen if date is selected.
- AdmissionFilterFragment for your right side screen if Admission is selected.
- RankFilterFragment for your right side screen if Rank is selected.

And in your Activity class you can handle the visibility of fragments accordingly.

Try below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Apply Filter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And to handle click of Clear and Apply Button, create interface with two methods apply(data) and clear(data) and implement these methods in all the right side fragments.

Comment: i arrange the same using fragments with in same activity but i need two buttons bottom of the activity i can't arrange layouts please give me an example how to arrange layout according to the picture

Comment: thanks bro thank you so much and also i do the same design in my way please correct me if any problem in design standard please refer my edited question thanks in advance